# Как удалить из длинного списка символы в конце каждой 10/30 строки?

Tags: notepad++

Например имеется вот такой список с случайными числами(начало символов не обязательно 765 может быть):

```
76561198172959359,
76561198340758079,
76561199116687352,
76561198307193850,
76561198969908277,
76561198332338679,
76561198391060592,
76561198357513005,
76561198168766254,
76561198185552042,
76561199083147627,
76561198147804964,
76561198307204581,
76561198172958054,
76561198294611232,
76561198332343901,
76561198219099485,
76561199062158302,
76561198890179039,
76561198865013141,
76561198894367308,
76561198219097672,
76561198386860426,
76561198332355978,
76561198319761419,
76561198214921483,
76561198315570694,
76561198911171591,
76561198386891456,
76561199020199491,
```

Как сделать так , что если например список будет состоять из 6245 строк , в конце каждой 30 или 10 строки удалить запятую?

Notepad++

Comment: для медитации: `$ for i in {1..100}; do echo "$i,"; done | sed '10~10s/,$//'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Установить курсор в начало строки, где нужно удалить запятую.
2. В меню выбрать макрос-Начать запись.
3. Последовательно нажать кнопки End-Backspace-Home-Down=количество строк.
4. В меню Макрос - остановить запись.
5. Перейти на следующую нужную строку.
6. В меню Макрос - Выполнить Многократный запуск, выполнить до конца файла.
   Предварительно сохранить копию файла.